# Python Selenium 4 - Firefox FirefoxBinary() Deprecated

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have upgraded to Selenium 4

```
new_binary_path = FirefoxBinary('path_to_binary')
selenium.webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path, options=ops, firefox_binary=new_binary_path)
```

or

```
options.add_argument("--setBinary(path_to_binary)")
selenium.webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path, options=ops)
```

Return this error message

```
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
```

**Documentation**

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md

Says

> Removed the firefox.Binary class. Custom binaries can still be
>   selected using firefox.Options#setBinary(). Likewise, custom binary
>   arguments can be specified with firefox.Options#addArguments()

**Does anyone know how to implement these changes?** I don't know what the hashtag means. I tried `options.setBinary()` but `setBinary()` is not recognised.

Comment: the changelog you are linking to is not for the python bindings.,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have solved the issue

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

#///////////////// Init binary & driver
new_driver_path = 'path to driver'
new_binary_path = 'path to binary'

ops = options()
ops.binary_location = new_binary_path
serv = Service(new_driver_path)
browser1 = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(service=serv, options=ops)
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to import a Service class from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service and put executable_path into Service.

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path="path_to_your_webdriver")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=service)
```

Answer (score 0):

After installing the new version I encountered this problem and solved it as follows. I hope it helps to other friends.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as options
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as Firefox_Options

firefox_options = Firefox_Options()
firefox_options.binary = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe';

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\dev\\geckodriver.exe',options=firefox_options)

driver.get('https://google.com')
```

Comment: This still throws the warning, and does not address the "Service object" warning.    ```C:\Users\PowerUser\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_29492\1343136057.py:10: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\webdrivers\\geckodriver.exe',options=firefox_options)```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
```

...implies that the argument [*`executable_path`* is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70099102/7429447) now and you need to pass a *`Service`* object instead.

---

### Details

This error is inline with the current implementation of webdriver and as per [webdriver.py](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/676c4cc8bbb0c113e5218e824df1fbd5d4a02a7d/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py#L101)

```
if executable_path != DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE_PATH:
    warnings.warn('executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object',
                  DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
```

additionally:

```
if firefox_binary:
    warnings.warn('firefox_binary has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object',
                  DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
```

---

### Solution

As per [Selenium v4.0 Beta 1](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/676c4cc8bbb0c113e5218e824df1fbd5d4a02a7d/py/CHANGES#L159):

> - Deprecate all but `Options` and `Service` arguments in driver instantiation. (#9125,#9128)

So:

- Instead of *`executable_path`* you have to use an instance of `Service()`.
- Instead of *`firefox_binary`* you have to use the *`binary_location`* property and pass it through an instance of `FirefoxOptions()`.
- You can use the following code block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

  option = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
  option.binary_location = '/path/to/firefox'
  driverService = Service('/path/to/geckodriver')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=driverService, options=option)
  driver.get("https://www.google.com")
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [DeprecationWarning: firefox_binary has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object using the argument firefox_binary in Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71452831/7429447)
- [Use Selenium with Brave Browser pass service object written in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69981271/7429447)