# Using IE selenium driver with python

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

im trying to define IE web driver to work with python and i have some errors that i cant undetrstand.
maby i have to change some security setting at internet explorer ?
i have interent explorer version 11
thank you .

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r"C:\Users\cohe\PycharmProjects\Testing\IEDriverServer.exe")

i got some errors:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cohe/PycharmProjects/Testing/Shrepoint.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r"C:\Users\cohe\PycharmProjects\Testing\IEDriverServer.exe")
  File "C:\Users\cohe\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\ie\webdriver.py", line 54, in __init__
    warnings.warn('executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object',
NameError: name 'warnings' is not defined
```

**Note**: I'm using selenium 4.0.0a1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Selenium 4 - Firefox FirefoxBinary() Deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296262/python-selenium-4-firefox-firefoxbinary-deprecated)

Answer (score 0):

It's not that clear which version of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) [python](/questions/tagged/python) clients you are using. However, the latest stable version of *Selenium Python* client is **v3.141.0**.

[image: SeleniumPythonAlpha]

So for production environment instead of **Selenium 4.0.0a1** you need to use **Selenium 3.141.0**

Additionally, as you are using the **raw** switch i.e. `r`, instead of the double quotes, you need to use the single quotes. Effectively your line of code will be:

```
driver = webdriver.Ie(executable_path=r'C:\Users\cohe\PycharmProjects\Testing\IEDriverServer.exe')
```

Comment: hi its not the problem.. i got the same error and tried both ways

Comment: @ניבבדלי Check out the updated answer and let me know your thoughts about it.

Answer (score 0):

What version of selenium are you using?

If you have a look at the python selenium bindings [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/ie/webdriver.py):

You can see 2 key parts:

```
 - executable_path - Deprecated: path to the executable. If the default is used it assumes the executable is in the $PATH
```

and

```
if executable_path != 'IEDriverServer.exe':
            warnings.warn('executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object',
                          DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
```

These were removed in the [selenium 4 alpha 1 bindings](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/d25b01eca78ae9982e3c1fed7f2294a91c186f54).

Your First, and best option:

Assuming you have the latest v4 selenium - This is in alpha testing and is subject to further and frequent change. Unless you need a cutting edge feature you might want to roll back your version to the latest stable. That should allow the executable path again.

Next options:
The error/warning is only thrown **If you try and specify the path**. The clue is in your error:

> 'executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object'

Therefore, don't specify it :-)

You can try:

1. Add your IeDriverSerice.exe location to PATH variable.
2. Place the IeDriverService.exe file in the same location as the script. Then you do not have to specify it and can leave it as default
3. Create a service object and see if that accepts the binary path.

Comment: im using selenium 4.0.0a1 and i cant understand where can i find IEdriver for this version of selenium . do you know where can i find it ? thank you !

Comment: @ניבבדלי If you're working with python use pip install selenium. And get your ie driver from the selenium website https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/

Comment: @RichEdwards Do visit [Selenium Chat Room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) and help other users.