# DeprecationWarning: firefox_binary has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object using the argument firefox_binary in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, geckodriver, tor

With the following code, on a Mac I tried to start Tor browser with Python and Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile
import os
import time

binary = '/Applications/Tor Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox'

# binary location
if os.path.exists(binary) is False:
    raise ValueError("The binary path to Tor firefox does not exist.")
firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary(binary)

browser = None

def get_browser(binary=None, options=None):
    global browser
    # only one instance of a browser opens
    if not browser:
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, options=options)
    return browser

browser = get_browser(binary=firefox_binary)

time.sleep(20)
browser.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
time.sleep(10)
html = browser.page_source
print(html)
```

This actually WORKS, but I get the following warning:

```
DeprecationWarning: firefox_binary has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary,options=options)
```

I searched for a way to pass this `Service` object, but nothing worked: substantially, I tried to pass the object the way other browsers do.

In fact, while other browsers have a documented [Service class](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/api.html#webdriver-firefox), even if I can import without any error `from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service` a `Service` class, the webdriver constructor doesn't feature any service object or it is not documented.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it is only warning so stop bother this. And as I know `Tor` uses little older `Firefox` - my `tor` on Linux uses Firefox `91.7` (and it is says it is `updated`), but normal Firefox has number `98.0` - so maybe `Service` doesn't work with older `Firefox`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message...

```
DeprecationWarning: firefox_binary has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary,options=options)
```

...implies that the argument *`firefox_binary`* is ***deprecated*** now and you need to pass a *`Service`* object instead.

---

### Details

This error is inline with the current implementation of webdriver as per [webdriver.py](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/676c4cc8bbb0c113e5218e824df1fbd5d4a02a7d/py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py#L107)

```
if firefox_binary:
    warnings.warn('firefox_binary has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object',
                  DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)
```

---

### Solution

As per [Selenium v4.0 Beta 1](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/676c4cc8bbb0c113e5218e824df1fbd5d4a02a7d/py/CHANGES#L159):

> - Deprecate all but `Options` and `Service` arguments in driver instantiation. (#9125,#9128)

So instead of *`firefox_binary`* you have to use the *`binary_location`* property and pass it through an instance of `FirefoxOptions()` as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

option = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
option.binary_location = r'/Applications/Tor Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox'
driverService = Service('/path/to/geckodriver')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=driverService, options=option)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Use Selenium with Brave Browser pass service object written in python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69981271/7429447)

Comment: Hey, I was about to vote it!   :-)   Anyway, I must say one thing: I tested your code, and I found it just works without any Service: the option.binary_location part is enough for the warning to disappear

Comment: Update to the previous comment: by not instantiating the Service, custom torrc file settings are ignored. I purposedly write it down in case someone comes here in the future  :-)